# Having trouble with K&R Exercise 5-11's requirements

Tags: c

The exercise:

> Modify the programs entab and detab (written as exercises in Chapter
>   1) to accept a list of tab stops as arguments. Use the default tab
>   settings if there are no arguments.

I'm not sure what a list of tab stops would be?

My guess:  ./entab -t 5,5,8,5

first tab stop is 5 spaces, second is 5, third is 8, forth is 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I did that exercise, I used "column" numbers.

```
./entab -t 4,8,12,32,66
```

That mimics the behavior of tab stops on a typewriter, a primitive machine which was much more popular when I did that exercise (and when K&R wrote the book) than it is today.

I miss typewriters.